# Why do I get "Collection was modified" errors from a ConcurrentDictionary when I'm only reading the values?

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency

I have a multi-threaded console project which is tied to RFID antennas that when turned on are scanning constantly. I have about 500 RFID tags in front of them and they scan about 15000 to 20000 per 30 seconds.

I was initially going to use ConcurrentDictionary or the Lazy version of the ConcurrentDictionary but it was not adding (and possibly updating) the tags. I verified this by just creating a basic List class of string and storing the tag in the same event the tag is scanned and on a separate timer event I compared the distinct list of the basic list with both ConcurrentDictionaries.

To explain about the use of ConcurrentDictionary, I'm saving a struct object that holds a datetime property (time scanned) and an expired property so that in my timer event, I can clean the collection of the expired items. The struct object takes a timespan object notating how long it is good for before it is expired. I'm using both versions of the ConcurrentDictionary because I'm still testing to see which one is better.

Then I thought to keep the generic list of string and use it as a raw data collector and every 30 seconds or so, get the distinct values and loop through them and use addorupdate to update the ConcurrentDictionary. Problem here is that I'm getting InvalidOperation exceptions (Collection was modified) iterating the list of the generic list even though I'm only reading the values. The loop is below. I've also tried making a copy of the generic list and using ToList() in the loop and I still get the exception.

```
static LazyConDeDupe<string, ConEntry> lDedupe = new LazyConDeDupe<string, ConEntry>(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
static private ConDeDupe dc = new ConDeDupe(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
static private List<string> epcs = new List<string>();
private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> missingList;
        List<string> lazyMissingList;

        lock (epcs)
        {
            List<string> disScans = epcs.Distinct().ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i <= disScans.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                dc.Add(disScans[i], System.DateTime.UtcNow);
                lDedupe.AddorUpdate(disScans[i], (k) => new ConEntry(System.DateTime.UtcNow, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)),
                                                 (r, v) => new ConEntry(DateTime.UtcNow, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)));
            }

            missingList = dc.FindNonExistantKeys(epcs);
            lazyMissingList = lDedupe.FindNonExistantKeys(epcs);


            if (missingList.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Found EPCs Missing");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Raw Count: {0}, Missing: {1}", epcs.Count.ToString(), missingList.Count.ToString()));
                missingList.ForEach(x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Missing EPC: {0}", x)));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Raw Count: {0}, Lazy Missing: {1}", epcs.Count.ToString(), lazyMissingList.Count.ToString()));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Distinct Raw Count: {0}", disScans.ToList().Distinct().Count().ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("None Missing - EPCs in List");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Raw Count: {0}, Missing: {1}", epcs.Count.ToString(), missingList.Count.ToString()));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Raw Count: {0}, Lazy Missing: {1}", epcs.Count.ToString(), lazyMissingList.Count.ToString()));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Distinct Raw Count: {0}", disScans.ToList().Distinct().Count().ToString()));
            }

            epcs.Clear();
        }
        if (dc.Count > 100000)
        {
            dc.CleanUp();                

        }
        else if(lazyMissingList.Count > 0) lDedupe.CleanUp();

    }

private static void OnTagsReported(ImpinjReader sender, TagReport report)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(string.Format("RFID Scanned, Tags:{0}", report.Tags.Count.ToString()));
        foreach (Tag tag in report)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"EPC: {0}", tag.Epc.ToString()));
            try
            {
                //dc.Add(tag.Epc.ToString(), System.DateTime.UtcNow);
                //lDedupe.AddorUpdate(tag.Epc.ToString(), (k) => new ConEntry(System.DateTime.UtcNow, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)),
                //                                        (r, v) => new ConEntry(DateTime.UtcNow, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)));
                epcs.Add(tag.Epc.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Why does a ConcurrentDictionary not be able to update using AddorUpdate method in some instances? The basic idea that I'm trying to do is store (Add) the distinct scans, modify when they were last scanned (update) and hold them for certain period of time until they expire (delete).

EDIT:
So I have rearranged my code in the elapsed event but to make things simple the issue is happening in this bit of code.

```
List<string> disScans = null;
lock (epcs)
{
    disScans = epcs.Distinct().ToList(); <------- Error occurs here
    epcs.Clear();
}
```

Comment: 2 things: 1) although you are creating disScans from epcs (your generic list), you are still probably iterating the list in the method calls: 'missingList = dc.FindNonExistantKeys(epcs)' and 'lDedupe.FindNonExistantKeys(epcs)'. 2) Because epcs is a static list, and therefore a shared resource, and is not concurrent, you must lock it everywhere you access it which includes in your OnTagsReported method.

Comment: I am iterating but I call the ToList extension method in the loop, does that also not work?  foreach (string epc in rawData.ToList())

Comment: Because you are locking epcs in Timer_Elapsed, you can use it however you would like - you do NOT have to call epcs.Distinct().ToList(). However, you MUST lock the list in OnTagsReported or you risk the possibility of one thread calling epcs.Add() while another thread is also adding to the list or is iterating through epcs in Timer_Elapsed. Also, although you call epcs.Distinct().ToList(), you are still accessing epcs in FindNonExistantKeys (dc.FindNonExistantKeys(epcs)) and by calling epcs.Clear (which modifies the list). TL;DR ==> lock the call to epcs.Add(tag...) in OnTagsReported

Comment: That was it, thank you! I added the lock OnTagsReported and it works. I also took out the other reference to epcs cause I don't need them anymore.

Comment: No problem - glad I was able to help!

Comment: The [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1#thread-safety) class is not thread-safe for concurrent readers and writers.